# Azure Kubernetes Containers to other internal vlans?

Tags: azure-aks

I'm trying to host my docker images behind Kubernetes. But, these docker images are making calls out to other resources on internal vlans. What I can't figure out is how do I enable that communications:

```
10.3.1.0/24 contains my internal api resources
10.3.2.0/24 contains other resources
10.3.5.0/24 container playground
```

What I would like to do is to say, host the Kubernetes in something like `10.3.3.0/24` and have them be able to access my internal APIs on the 10.3.1.0 network.

I can't seem to figure out that part.

I do know that if I manually create an instance of my docker image in the 10.3.5.0 space then I can get to the 10.3.1.0 space.

Comment: so whats the issue. if you are using azure cni than containers have an ip address on the resource group and can talk to anything their worker node can talk to and vice versa

Comment: I can't seem to get the containers to see the other vlans.   I think what I'm missing is the setup for Kubernetes.     Somewhere I have to be able to tell aks to use the 10.3.5.0 vlan.   They don't seem to land there.

Comment: vlans? azure doesnt have vlans. at least i dont think it has

Comment: In my world, each of the lans above is a vlan to me.   10.3.1.0/24 is one vlan, 10.3.2.0 is another.     So somehow I need the AKS containers, from what ever vlan they are in, to be able to talk to resources in the other vlans.  

Something like, a container that's reaching out to a SQL instance, or perhaps another API in a VM, etc.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in Azure, there just has the Vnet and the subnet inside the Vnet. So what you said the vlan is called subnet in Azure.

And as the comment says, when you use the [Azure CNI (advanced) networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#azure-cni-advanced-networking), then pods get full virtual network connectivity and can be directly reached from outside of the cluster, it means you can access the other resources of Azure in the different subnets of one Vnet. You can read the article about the [behavior differences exist between kubenet and Azure CNI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#compare-network-models).

Here is also an example:

You create the AKS cluster with the CNI networking in the subnet1 and the VM in the subnet2, both subnets in the same Vnet. You deploy an API server in the VM. Then you can access the API server with the VM private IP directly.

Comment: I finally got to a point where I could see what's going on.   Essentially I was flying blind to see how it all works.  In the end, I ended up creating a new container using: [Getting a shell to a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) method and starting pinging from there.   Until I got that far, it was really hard to figure out what I had working and what I did not.

Comment: @NickJacobs What is the situation now? And what did you want to know?

Comment: @NickJacobs Any more questions? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: @NickJacobs Well, if it solves your problem please accept it as the answer.